# Automatic Cookie clear in Android - Chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, cookies, session-cookies

On killing Chrome App in android, i expect the session cookies to be cleared, but they stay intact and affects certain functionalities of my site when the user re-visits the site. The same is not observed in iOS.

Is this the expected behavior ? Clearing cookies explicitly is the only option in Android ?

Comment: Looks like problem with your app rather than Chrome.

Comment: Its a site and not an app. A site running on Chrome

Comment: I know. By app I mean web based app